# How to start an application in Docker container after restarting the container not starting the application?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine, docker-registry

I have written a Dockerfile, using this file I have created a Docker image also successfully built a container. After building a container I have installed some software manually in that time that application was working fine. But after restarting the container that application not working. To start the application I need to run the commands manually. Can you help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: In general you should not do that!!! the best solution is recreate de image with all you need to run the software..

Comment: You should be able to cleanly restart the application by `docker rm` your existing container and `docker run` a new one.  As @Marco notes this will lose any changes you've made in a `docker exec` shell; avoid doing that.

Answer (score 1):

That is the precise difference between a virtual machine and docker container. All the installable software to a docker container should come from docker image and not by installing in the container. Follow what @Marco suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the installation commands to the Dockerfile as `RUN` commands so everything you need is installed at the point the image is created